# Is cheap soap vegan?

Tags: veganism, is-it-vegan, travel, cosmetics

What ingredients in soap are not vegan?

I'm not asking if soaps that are labeled "vegan" are vegan. That's obvious.

I live in a very small town in South America. Actually I have to travel 20 km down a very bumpy road by bicycle to get to a very small town. There are no fancy stores here with soap that are marked "vegan".

Of course, I know that animal fats are not vegan, but I do not think that the bottom-shelf cheap soaps use animal fat (that's a fancy and expensive ingredient).

But what other ingredients in soap might not be vegan? What should I look-for in soap to make sure it's cruelty-free?

In general, are cheap soaps vegan?

Comment: I misread this first as "cheap SOUP" and I thought that it was an odd and tough question.